# Extract parameters from string, included quoted regions, in Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt, split

I have a Qt5/C++ program which receives a QString containing a program name and possibly parameters.  I need to split this QString into multiple strings.  For example, the string

```
/tmp/myprog --param1 --param2=2 --param3="1 2 3" -p 4
```

Should split into:

```
list[0]=/tmp/myprog
list[1]=--param1
list[2]=--param2=2
list[3]=--param3="1 2 3"
list[4]=-p 4
```

My first thought was to use the "split" method on a space, but that would break param3 which is quoted.  As well parameter 4 has no : or = between the -p and 4.

Is there a simple way to do this?  I suspect the -p 4 is impossible to split up easily since there is no way of knowing if the 2 items below together.

But is there a split/regex/other way to split the above?  (If we ignore the -p 4 is it possible?)

---

Update:

Could the same function split the string without the --param or -p?  so a string of

```
abc "a a" "b b b"  c
```

would become

```
list[0]=abc
list[1]="a a"
list[2]="b b b"
list[3]=c
```

Comment: Maybe you can involve `QCommandLineParser` here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two aspects of your task:

1. Splitting of the command line into arguments. This needs to be implemented from scratch.
2. Processing of the arguments to extract parameters and their values. Since Qt 5.2, you can use `QCommandLineParser` to do that.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QDebug>

static QStringList splitCommandLine(const QString & cmdLine)
{
    QStringList list;
    QString arg;
    bool escape = false;
    enum { Idle, Arg, QuotedArg } state = Idle;
    foreach (QChar const c, cmdLine) {
        if (!escape && c == '\\') { escape = true; continue; }
        switch (state) {
        case Idle:
            if (!escape && c == '"') state = QuotedArg;
            else if (escape || !c.isSpace()) { arg += c; state = Arg; }
            break;
        case Arg:
            if (!escape && c == '"') state = QuotedArg;
            else if (escape || !c.isSpace()) arg += c;
            else { list << arg; arg.clear(); state = Idle; }
            break;
        case QuotedArg:
            if (!escape && c == '"') state = arg.isEmpty() ? Idle : Arg;
            else arg += c;
            break;
        }
        escape = false;
    }
    if (!arg.isEmpty()) list << arg;
    return list;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QCommandLineParser parser;
    parser.addHelpOption();
    QCommandLineOption param1("param1");
    QCommandLineOption param2("param2", "", "val2");
    QCommandLineOption param3("param3", "", "val3");
    QCommandLineOption param4("p", "", "val4");
    parser.addOption(param1);
    parser.addOption(param2);
    parser.addOption(param3);
    parser.addOption(param4);
    if (true) {
        // Parse a string
        QString cmdLine("/tmp/myprog --param1 --param2=2\\ 2 --param3=\"1 2 3\" -p 4");
        parser.parse(splitCommandLine(cmdLine));
    } else {
        // Parse a command line passed to this application
        parser.process(app);
    }
    if (parser.isSet(param1)) qDebug() << "param1";
    if (parser.isSet(param2)) qDebug() << "param2:" << parser.value(param2);
    if (parser.isSet(param3)) {
        QStringList values = parser.value(param3)
                .split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
        qDebug() << "param3:" << values;
    }
    if (parser.isSet(param4)) qDebug() << "param4:" << parser.value(param4);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
param1
param2: "2 2"
param3: ("1", "2", "3")
param4: "4"
```

`QDebug` quotes the strings it outputs. The strings themselves don't contain any quotes.

Comment: Are you sure about the output for param2 ?  If correct, not sure I understand why.

Comment: @GenerationDSystems Well, look at what I pass as the input. It's on purpose, to show that escaping works correctly.

Comment: I tried your code with '/usr/bin/logger "customstart" "param 2"' and got output ("/usr/bin/logger", "customstartparam", "2").  I'll dig deeper but suspect something isn't quite right.

Comment: @GenerationDSystems I don't see any dashes in your parameters. Maybe you meant `/usr/bin/logger --customstart --param 2`, you'd then also need to add the `customstart` and `param` as parameters to the parser. It works just fine. The quotes around `"--param 2"` are invalid and aren't supposed to work, since the space isn't part of the parameter name. To quote as you did implies that `param 2` is the command option name taken in entirety, with the space in it. The implementation is true to your question. If you need something else, amend the question.

Comment: @GenerationDSystems When passed the input as you state, the `splitCommandLine` produces the following three strings: `("/usr/bin/logger", "customstart", "param 2")`. This is correct and not the output you get. The command line parser doesn't know what to do with it afterwards, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the particulars of Qt, however with a quick look at the documentation for QString, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html), I believe that the following code *should* work (albeit inefficiently).

```
#include<QString>
#include<vector>

vector<QString> list; //vector used for variable length parameter requirements
QString args; //The arguments string
bool quoteFlag = false;
for(int i=0; i<args.size(); i++){
    QString qstr = "";
    while(args.at(i) != QChar(' ') || quoteFlag){ //loops if character is not ' ' or is within a set of quotes
        if(args.at(i) == QChar('\"'){
            quoteFlag = !quoteflag; //basically says, "you are now within a set of quotes"
        }
        qstr += args.at(i); //add current character to qstr
        i++
    }
    list.push_back(qstr) //add qstr to the argument list
}
```

Again, I do not use any Qt libraries, and this code is untested, but, if I understand the documentation, it *should* work.

As far as the `-p 4` bit goes, that is not possible with your current syntax for the other arguments.

Comment: I think that will work - but my gut tells me there is something simple using Qt libraries...but I can't find it.  I wonder too if there is a RegEx that can intelligently group items in quotes, etc...

Comment: There is a regex version of split(), however, I kinda ran out of time to write this, but if I can design one for you, I will edit my answer in a bit and put it in there.

Comment: After some long consideration and testing, I could not find a way to split the string between arguments without severely altering the resulting strings. Sorry, but I don't think using a regex is possible under these circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

> Extract parameters from string, included quoted regions, in Qt

When parsing any "escaped" or quoted string: `splitArgs` (from KF5) was immensely useful.

The following source code manages "escaping" and more; from

```
    one two a\ b "c d e"
```

it prints

```
    one
    two
    a b
    c d e
```

The core of the source code is just a `splitArgs` call:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <KShell>

int main()
{
    QString whole = "one two a\\ b \"c d e\"";
    QTextStream(stdout) << whole << endl << "--------------------" << endl;

    QStringList group = KShell::splitArgs("one two a\\ b \"c d e\"");
    for (auto element: group) {
        QTextStream(stdout) << element << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QStringList argumentsList =  QProcess::splitCommand(arguments);`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#splitCommand