# getting part of QString after a specific term

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QString which looks soemwaht like this

```
QString args = "perl /path#to#a#pe#lprogram -conf /path#to#a#conf#file -outdir /path#to#output#dir -outfile /path#to#output#file"
```

I want to assign /path#to#output#dir and /path#to#output#file" which comes after -outdir and -outfile to a new QString variable.

I am new to QT.

Comment: This is an **exact** duplicate of [Extract parameters from string, included quoted regions, in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068750/extract-parameters-from-string-included-quoted-regions-in-qt). It's just worded differently, but both questions ask of the same thing, and the solution presented there is equally applicable.

Comment: thankyou for all the comments (especially Ashot). This was fairly easy. the problem was my unfamiliarity with QT functions. here is the code :

    QString args = "perl /path#to#a#pe#lprogram -conf /path#to#a#conf#file -outdir /path#to#output#dir -outfile /path#to#output#file"
    QStringList query = args.split(" ");
    for (int i=0; i < query.size(); i++)
    {
    if (query.at(i).contains("-outputdir"))
    {
        odir = query.at(i+1).trimmed();
    }
    if (query.at(i).contains("-outputfile"))
    {
        ofile = query.at(i+1).trimmed();
    }
    }

thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be splitting `args` into strings and search for `outdir` and `outfile` in stringlist.

Split it using this function http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#split

Also you should consider this class http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments (especially Ashot). This was fairly easy. the problem was my unfamiliarity with QT functions. here is the code :

```
QString args = "perl /path#to#a#pe#lprogram -conf /path#to#a#conf#file -outdir /path#to#output#dir -outfile /path#to#output#file"
QStringList query = args.split(" ");
for (int i=0; i < query.size(); i++)
{
if (query.at(i).contains("-outputdir"))
{
    odir = query.at(i+1).trimmed();
}
if (query.at(i).contains("-outputfile"))
{
    ofile = query.at(i+1).trimmed();
}
}
```

thankyou !