# How to escape the delimiter when splitting a QString?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qstring

How can i split a `QString` by a character, e.g.: `'+'` and do not split when that character is escaped: `'\+'`?

Thanks!

As requested, some more detail:

The String to split: `"a+\+"`

The delimiter: `'+'`

The desired output: `"a"`, `"+"`

Comment: While `"(?<!\\\\)\\+"` will work in most cases, it will still fail in some (when `+` is preceded with a literal ``\``).

Comment: Could you share the code you have?

Comment: Added the in- and output i would like to achieve. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`globalMatch`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#globalMatch) with a regular expression to split that selects everything but a non-escaped `'+'`:

```
(?:[^\\\+]|\\.)*
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/bP8oM0/1)

So given `QString foo` you can iterate through the list using a [`QRegularExpressionMatchIterator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatchiterator.html):

```
QRegularExpression bar("((?:[^\\\\\\+]|\\\\.)*)");
auto it = bar.globalMatch(foo);

while(it.hasNext()){
    cout << it.next().captured(1).toStdString() << endl;
}
```

---

In C++11 you can also use a [`cregex_token_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator):

```
regex bar("((?:[^\\\\\\+]|\\\\.)+)");
copy(cregex_token_iterator(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), bar, 1), cregex_token_iterator(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

[<kbd>Live Exampe</kbd>](http://ideone.com/1NDbBF)

---

In the unfortunate event that you have neither Qt5, nor C++11, nor Boost, you can use [`QRegExp`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html):

```
QRegExp bar("((?:[^\\\\\\+]|\\\\.)*)");

for(int it = bar.indexIn(foo, 0); it >= 0; it = bar.indexIn(foo, it)) {
    cout << bar.cap(1).toStdString() << endl;
}
```

Comment: This should also work with Qt4 and using `QRegExp` class instead of `QRegularExpression` or?  Because this leaves me with `++` when splitting `foo+\+` and `+` when splitting `foo+bar` when it should be `foo, +` and `foo, bar`

Comment: @tobilocker What's the command you're using cause this should work with a `QRegExp` as well.

Comment: So `QString values` is: `"EXPRESSION+\+"` and spliiting is done with: `QStringList valuesList = values.split(QRegExp("(?:[^\\\\\\+]|\\\\.]*"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);`. And i get: `"+"`

Comment: @tobilocker You failed to copy the regex correctly. You used a closing bracket not a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but actually it is correct in the code :)

Comment: @tobilocker Ugh you're right, I thought that negated, and it does not. Do you have C++11, if so I'll suggest a solution there. (I've updated to show you how to do it with Qt5.)

Comment: Unfortunately not and i can't update since i'm working on a companies R&D account which is very limited. Qt version is 4.6.2 and gcc is 4.4.7

Comment: @tobilocker Boost? It'll include `boost::cregex_token_iterator` which will work the same way. If not I'll tool up an example using ye olde `QRegExp`

Comment: No Boost (allthough it's a shame). It would be very kind to provide a solution for my ancient setup :)

Comment: @tobilocker Edited with great sadness. You should start considering looking at Stack Overflow Careers...

Answer (score 0):

If, instead of a "+" as a separator, you can use space as a separator... `splitArgs` does the work for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977326/2660408